# Iterating forward and backward in Python

Tags: python, iteration

I have a coding interface which has a counter component. It simply increments by 1 with every update. Consider it an infinite generator of {1,2,3,...} over time which I HAVE TO use.

I need to use this value and iterate from -1.5 to 1.5. So, the iteration should start from -1.5 and reach 1.5 and then from 1.5 back to -1.5.

How should I use this infinite iterator to generate an iteration in that range?

Comment: In what increment?

Comment: Provide an example input and output, to make it less confusing.

Comment: @Jeremy - provide us a sample of what you have tried thus far and how it didn't satisfy your needs. Asking us to solve your problem for you without helping us see what you have attempted is a bit like asking us to do your homework for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all.

I guess the best approach is to use the trigonometric functions (**sine** or **cosine**) which oscillate between plus and minus one.

More details at: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cycle` from `itertools` to repeat a sequence.

```
from itertools import cycle

# build the list with 0.1 increment
v = [(x-15)/10 for x in range(31)]
v = v + list(reversed(v))
cv = cycle(v)

for c in my_counter:
    x = next(cv)
```

This will repeat the list `v`:

```
 -1.5, -1.4, -1.3, -1.2, -1.1, -1.0, -0.9, -0.8, -0.7, -0.6, -0.5, -0.4, 
 -0.3, -0.2, -0.1, 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0,
 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.4, 1.3, 1.2, 1.1, 1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 
 0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.0, -0.1, -0.2, -0.3, -0.4, -0.5, -0.6, 
 -0.7, -0.8, -0.9, -1.0, -1.1, -1.2, -1.3, -1.4, -1.5, -1.5, -1.4, -1.3, 
 -1.2, -1.1, -1.0, -0.9, -0.8, -0.7, -0.6, -0.5, -0.4, -0.3, -0.2, -0.1, 
 0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 
 1.4, 1.5, 1.5, 1.4, 1.3, 1.2, 1.1, 1.0, 0.9 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
import itertools

infGenGiven = itertools.count() # This is similar your generator

def func(x):
    if x%2==0:
        return 1.5
    else:
        return -1.5

infGenCycle = itertools.imap(func, infGenGiven)

count=0
while count<10:
    print infGenCycle.next()
    count+=1
```

Output:

```
1.5
-1.5
1.5
-1.5
1.5
-1.5
1.5
-1.5
1.5
-1.5
```

Note that this starts 1.5 because the first value in *infGenGiven* is 0, although for your generator it is 1 and so the *infGenCycle* output will give you what you want.